# Cannot free data of a buffer after it was reallocated inside recursive function. What can be the reason?

Tags: c, realloc

So I faced with an issue - when I have data that exceeds initial size of my buffer and I do reallocation inside recursive function then I get an error for freeing its buffer.

> *malloc: *** error for object 0x100106da0: pointer being freed was not allocated*

Here is the code:

```
void recPrint(FILE *file, char *buffer, int realBufferSize, int bufferSize, char *freeCh, NodePtr* temp){

   //some code here...

    int *intArr = temp -> usedIndices;
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 36; i++){
        if(intArr[i] == 1){
            if(i > 9){
                *freeCh = i - 10 + 'a' ;
            }else{
                *freeCh = i + '0';
            }
            realBufferSize++;
            if (realBufferSize >= bufferSize){
                buffer = realloc(buffer, (bufferSize + 100) * sizeof(char)); // <<--- REALLOC here
                bufferSize += 100;
            }
            freeCh++;
            recPrint(file, buffer, realBufferSize, bufferSize, freeCh, &temp -> children[i]);

            //now we need to remove all extra characters till the next turn
            freeCh--;
            *freeCh = '\0';
        }
    }

}

void printTrie(FILE *file, char *initialPath){

    initPath = initialPath;
    if(root.isParent == 0) return;
    char *buffer;
    char *freeCh;
    int *intArr = root.usedIndices;
    int bufferSize = 10;
    int realBufferSize = 1000;

    int i = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < 36; i++){
        buffer = calloc(1001, sizeof(char));
        freeCh = buffer;

        if(intArr[i] == 1){
            if(i > 9){
                *freeCh = i - 10 + 'a' ;
            }else{
                *freeCh = i + '0';
            }

        freeCh++;
        realBufferSize++;
        recPrint(file, buffer, realBufferSize, bufferSize, freeCh, &root.children[i]);
        free(buffer); //<<--- getting error here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ла-ла-ла-ла-ла-ла-ла-ла :-)

Comment: The original pointer value is long-gone after a `realloc`. The caller's value of said pointer doesn't change, and is invalid as soon as `realloc` is performed (note it is passed **by-value** throughout that recursive call chain).

Comment: @WhozCraig wow... what is the classic workaround here?

Comment: @PutinHuylo Pass the pointer by address (pointer-to-pointer) throughout the call chain, including the originator, or utilize the `rePrint` return result to always return the current value of the buffer pointer to push the value back up the call chain when the recursion unwinds. Either will work. R.Sahu's answer below demonstrates the latter of these, and is definitely work a look.

Comment: @WhozCraig I tried both. neither really works for me...
so when I try to path pointer-to-pointer I am patching &buffer
and I have char **buffer as a function argument.
But then I have error for realloc! It says that it was never allocated. What can I do here?

Return char* does not work either, still same error

Comment: @WhozCraig are there any other ideas? I have indexer(6296,0x7fff79c1f310) malloc: *** error for object 0x100200158: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed. after using free on the returned value of recPrint.

Comment: I still don't know whether you're doing this right, but the only thing left I would suggest is rethinking the resize math. it seems to me your bufferSize originally passed is initially one-less than the actual buffer size (I assume because you're making space for a terminator), but the *resize* logic does NOT follow suit with that. exceeding your boundary by-one on the edge would corrupt your malloc free-chain to be sure, so look closely there.

Comment: @WhozCraig I tried like everything.. here is code when I return char * value
http://www.codeshare.io/W1z0w

Comment: @WhozCraig Ok, as discovered - realloc simply returns NULL.. what can be the reason? errno gives unidentified error...

Comment: I will virtually guarantee you're writing outside your allocation boundaries. This should be run under Valgrind. Doing so will nearly guarantee where your overwrite is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment from @WhozCraig points out the problem. Here's a suggested fix.

1. Return the `realloc`ed buffer from `recPrint`.
2. Use `free` on the returned value of `recPrint`.

```cpp
char* recPrint(FILE *file, char *buffer, int realBufferSize,
               int bufferSize, char *freeCh, NodePtr* temp){

   ....

   // where you recurse...
   buffer = recPrint(file, buffer, realBufferSize, 
                     bufferSize, freeCh, &temp -> children[i]);

   // and always return the *current* buffer pointer back to the caller.
   return buffer;
}
```

In `printTrie`:

```
    buffer = recPrint(file, buffer, realBufferSize, bufferSize, freeCh, &root.children[i]);
    free(buffer);
```

Comment: Neither way works for me really, When I return realloced buffer I have same error... Probably it is smth to do with recursion...
When I path pointer-to-pointer I cannot do realloc inside recPrint, it gives me similar error

Comment: @PutinHuylo Not sure if you included the necessary special sauce. A recursive call requires you retain *that* potentially resized buffer pointer return result. See the addendum to the posted answer above.

Comment: Well, now I have the following error in the same place:
indexer(6296,0x7fff79c1f310) malloc: *** error for object 0x100200158: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug